# Django is rendering empty template to create new profile instead of submitting form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

First some code:

**models.py**

```
class Findings(models.Model):
patient = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
finding_type = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True)
upload = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
date_created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.finding_type
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddFindingForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Findings

    fields = ('finding_type', 'description', 'upload', 'patient')
    labels = {
        'finding_type' : _('Rodzaj badania'),
        'description': _('Opis'),
        'upload': _('Dodaj plik'),

    }
```

**views.py**

```
def add_finding(request):

form = AddFindingForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.patient = request.user.profile
        form.save()
        return redirect('profile')

context = {'form': form}

return render(request, 'add_finding.html', context)
```

**template**

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p}}
      <button type="submit"> Wyślij </button>
 </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

So, everytime i'm trying to submit a filled form it displays another form to create new Profile, even if i'm setting patient manually.
The empty form it's displaying is on the same url.
I have no idea why it's doing that...

Comment: Is this incorrect `form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`?

Comment: God dammit! Thank You man! i was looking at it for an hour and didn't saw this basic copy/paste error!

It's my first post here, should i delete it now or leave it?

Comment: Up to you, If you want to leave this I'll be able to post it as an answer and you can accept it?

Comment: sure, I can leave it, I need to mark your comment somehow as an answer?

Comment: I added it as an answer you can click tick (left side of answer) so it turns green to mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting your `request.POST` data to wrong form. Doing this user's submitted data never gets into `AddFindingForm()` instead it should be,

```
def add_finding(request):
    form = AddFindingForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddFindingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  # Change Here
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.patient = request.user.profile
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'add_finding.html', context)
```